How to call a postgresql function that expects an array of custom types from Azure (node)
I have an Azure function written in node. This function connects to a postgresql database using the pg library. It then calls a posgresql function that upserts some data.
When the postgresql function has simple parameters, it works great.
However, I'd like to have the postgresql function expect an array of custom types. E.g.:
CREATE TYPE fund_type AS (
    symbol char(5),
    fund_name text,
    fee DOUBLE PRECISION
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_upsert_funds(
    funds fund_type[]
)
...

In the Azure function, I have something like this:
const funds = [
    {
        symbol: "ABCDX"
        fund_name: "Acme Fund"
        fee: 0.25
    },
    {
        symbol: "BCDEX"
        fund_name: "Beta Fund"
        fee: 0.40
    },
]

const res = await client.query('SELECT * from fn_upsert_funds($1::fund_type[])', [funds]);

This doesn't work - I get an error: malformed record literal error.
I'm sure I need to format/structure the parameter differently, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to do it.
Thanks in advance for your advice!

To call a PostgreSQL function that expects an array of custom types from Azure (node), you need to format/structure the parameter differently. You can use the pg-format library to format the parameter as a string and then pass it to the function.
